# Nested if and else statements in loops

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me why this program won't print numbers and execute properly? I have tried using continue and break but nothing seems to work.

enter code here

```
n=60
m=2
for int in range(60):
        if n/m==int:
                m=2
                n=n+1
        else:
                while m<=n and n/m==float:
                         m=m+1
                         if n==m:
                                 print(n)
```

Comment: You're shadowing the builtin `int` and `float`, please change your loop variable. Also, you never define `float`.

Comment: There are a multitude of problems one of which is you are checking if `n/m` is equal to a type which is never going to be True.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve as I cannot follow any sort of logic from your code?

Comment: What is this script supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with some of the changes that the commenters above mentioned:

```
n = 60
m = 2
for value in range(60):  # Don't use the word `int`!
    if n/m == value:
        m = 2
        n += 1
    else:
        while m <= n and n/m == something:  # `something` is undefined!
            m += 1
            if n == m:
                print(n)
```

The main problem (at this point) is that the variable `something` (that you had called `float`) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do. But to make it syntactically correct.

1. For variable names don't use built in types like `int`etc.
2. To check for types, you should use `isinstance`
3. If for python 2 use from `__future__ import division`

Code:

```
 from __future__ import division
    n=60
    m=2
    for i in range(60):
            if isinstance(n/m,int):
                    m=2
                    n=n+1
            else:
                    while m<=n and isinstance(n/m,float):
                            m=m+1
                            if n==m:
                                    print(n)
```